# Python ssl server reporting TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA

Tags: python, ssl

I have a Python SSL server that uses a self-signed certificate. I start my server like this:

```py
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 443), MyHTTPHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True, cert_reqs=0)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I get the following error when I connect using Firefox:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51194)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 734, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 621, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:1751)
----------------------------------------
```

I do not see this behavior with Chrome or another client. It only happens on the first connection (complaints about certificate) until I accept the certificate. The exception actually does not cause the program to quit.

Why am I getting an error on the server? How can I avoid the exception?

Comment: Could it be because Firefox is sending a client certificate?

Comment: I'm not sure but my code should not check for the client certificate (cert_reqs=0). it seems to be specific to firefox. (I added more details to Question).

Comment: Note that now that letsencrypt exists, there is no reason to use self-signed certificates any longer.

Comment: It depends. Not all domains are supported. I can't get a certificate with hostname.region.compute.amazonaws.com, for example.

Answer (score 12):

The `TLv1 unknown CA` alert is sent by some clients if they cannot verify the certificate of the server because it is signed by an unknown issuer CA. You can avoid this kind of exception if you use a certificate which is already trusted by the client or which can be validated against a root CA of the client (don't forget to include the chain certificates too).

If you cannot avoid this error (for instance because you are using a self-signed certificate) then you have to catch the exception and deal with it by closing the connection. You might need to do this by using `handle_request` to handle each request by itself and catch exceptions instead of using `serve_forever`.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused why the server is complaining about unknown CA on a client. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as you, even though I had a signed certificate from Sectigo. Turns out, you need a ***certificate chain*** rather than only your domain's certificate itself.
[Source](https://medium.com/two-cents/certificate-chain-example-e37d68c3a3f0#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20file%20with%20the%20certificate%20chain,AWS%20Certificate%20manager%3A%20cat%20TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt%20USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt%20%3E%20Certificate_Chain.crt)

While referring to this site, and the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YjX7rtiAsk
, I found that I need to create a new file called certificate-chain.pem, and manually/with the help of scripts concatenate (join) three certificates - domain certificate, CA certificate and the USERTrust certificate, one after the other.
Then, in the file you need, point to this certificate bundle/chain. This is a solution which I wept on for 7 hours.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Since I used certbot, I was able to simply changed the certfile from `certfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem'` to `certfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'` and it worked instantly